# Save stacked image as single image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have this code that at the end of it I stack 2 images together using np.dstack. However, when I try to save the result as an image it gives the following error:

> error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function
> 'imwrite'
>
> > Overload resolution failed:
> >
> > - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

The code is I am using is provided below along with the reference image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


#Read Image
img = cv2.imread('Input-Set/Original1.tif')

# Convert into gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Image processing ( smoothing )
# Averaging
blur = cv2.blur(gray,(3,3))

#Threshold The Image
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(blur,145,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
inverted = np.invert(th1)

#Threshold The Background
ret,th2 = cv2.threshold(blur,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#inverted2 = np.invert(th2)

# # Black background
# blackblankimage = np.zeros(shape=[1024, 998], dtype=np.uint8)

#Mask Background over Threshold Image
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(inverted, inverted, mask=th2)

height = 998
width = 1024
lum_img = Image.new('L', [height,width] , 0)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(lum_img)
draw.pieslice([(16,37), (960,985)], 0, 360, 
              fill = 255, outline = "white")
img_arr =np.array(th1)
lum_img_arr =np.array(lum_img)

final_img_arr = np.dstack((lum_img_arr,img_arr))
inverted2 = np.invert(FinalImage)
FinalImage2 = Image.fromarray(inverted2)

cv2.imwrite('Output-Set/FinalImage2.tif', FinalImage2)
```

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa7xk.png)

Comment: Images must have either 1 or 3 channels.  You only have 2.

Comment: @fmw42 I know that I have 2. I have tried to convert it into 1 channel but it didn't work. Do you know of any method I can follow to do so?

Comment: Convert the image to BGR before saving it.

Comment: @stateMachine it still gives error that the number of channels is 2

Comment: It is generally bad idea to mix libraries like that. You are using PIL and OpenCV, and they are not 100% compatible. Whatever you are passing to `imwrite` is not a numpy array. Anyway, try saving the image via PIL using the `save` method.

Comment: @stateMachine I have tried using the PIL save, however, when I try to load the image again it loads it as blank circle, even though it is saved on my PC as cracked image. It works only if I open the image with paint and resaved it again. But there should be a way around it.